# using ember ember-drag-sort with emblem templates

Tags: ember.js, ember-drag-sort

Error parsing code while looking for "npm:" imports in file: /{path}/tmp/stub_generator-input_base_path-8FTPYOxJ.tmp/dash/tests/pages/components/_component.js
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (35:13)

this when i try to run my project or build

i am using
ember 3.12
emblem 0.12.0
ember-drag-sort 3.0

Comment: Hi! Not sure what is going on there, but it seems to be related to Emblem more than to `ember-drag-sort`. Emblem has not been updated in two years. I'm sorry but the only thing I have to suggest is to consider phasing out Emblem from your project.

Comment: I see but local when start the project i edit emblem option in environment file the project run after edit emblem option but on build i get error and stop the process

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the problem it maby because of spread es6 so
I added

```
babel: {
  plugins: [require.resolve('@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread')]
},
```

to ember-cli-build.js it worked